# The click event is not working

Tags: jquery

Can someone point me in the right direction in figuring out why the event in the code below is not working. I tried using firefox but not sure how to troubleshooting this problem using firefox.

When I click on the button, nothing happens. I don't see the alert box

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     $(#saveButton).click(function()
     {
         alert("hello World");
     });
 });
 </script>

 <div id="west" class="ui-layout-west">
    <input id="saveButton" type="button" value="save"></input>
    <div> <ul id="ul_west"></ul> </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should be looking at a debug console (Firebug or Chrome) and this javascript error would have been pointed out to you exactly by the debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around the id.

```
$('#saveButton').click(function(){
     alert("hello World");
 });
```

Comment: Lol. Poor guy, I can only say *we've all been there*.

Comment: Hah, yeah. Syntax highlighting helps ALOT when spotting these things.

Comment: Amen... Last year I spent about 2 hours trying to solve a javascript problem like this... I had declared a variable using a reserved keyword... sleep deprivation doesn't help programming ability

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#saveButton').click(function() // forgot '
     {
         alert("hello World");
     });
```